# Web api windows authentication custom role provider not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I've created a new Web API project using Visual studio 2015 and it runs well. Then I added the following steps.

1. Create tables for roles, roleMembers and use code first to create all the data access code
2. Create a custom role provider class which inherit RoleProvider
3. Update the web.config file to use the custom role provicer
4. Decorate the control method with [Authorize(Roles ="TestRole"]

Details:

The following tables which are used to store roles and membership are created.

```
create table Roles (Id int primary key, Role nvarchar(50) not null)
create TABLE RoleMember (RoleId int references Roles(Id), userId varchar(50) not null primary key(RoleId, userId))
```

The customized role provider code is

```
namespace webapi.Models
{
    public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName { .... }
        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames) { .... }
        public override void CreateRole(string roleName) { .... }
        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole) { .... }
        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch) { .... }
        public override string[] GetAllRoles() { .... }
        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext()) // break point set here
            {
                var roles = from rm in db.RoleMembers
                            from r in db.Roles
                            where r.Id == rm.RoleId && rm.userId == username
                            select r.Role;
                if (roles!=null)
                {
                    return roles.ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new string[] { };
                }
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName) { .... }
        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext()) // Break point set here
            {
                var roles = from rm in db.RoleMembers
                            from r in db.Roles
                            where r.Id == rm.RoleId && rm.userId == username
                            select r.Role;
                if (roles!=null)
                {
                    return roles.Any(r=> r.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames) { .... }
        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName) { .... }
    }
}
```

The web.config file has been updated.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="webapi.Models.MyRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

Then the controller is decorated.

```
namespace webapi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "TestRole")] // The web api call returns value before add this line
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
```

However, testing "http://localhost:23151/api/MyController" got the error of "
Authorization has been denied for this request.
" so I set the break points in customized role provider. But none of them can be hit when debugging?

Comment: Are you using OWIN Auth? Are you sure that you are passing the correct headers in your call? Because if there's not an authorized user, the call won't hit the breakpoint. I may be wrong, but I think that  it will check if there's a valid token firstly, then it will validate the role.

Comment: I'm using Windows authentication. The the project is create using the template in VS 2015 so I guess it's OWIN?

Comment: Yes, I think it is. Are you sending a token in the headers of the http call?

Comment: I don't know how to send a token in the http call? I changed `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in web.config so I think IIS will handle these details? Right now I don't have any client yet. I'm testing by typing the url in browser.

Comment: you are right! you don't have to pass any credentials in the http request. Please, forgive me.

Comment: Are you running from the visual studio IIS or a separated IIS server ?

Comment: I'm running from the visual studio IIS express (the default, I didn't change any default setting of visual studio 2015 yet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88520/discussion-between-dc7a9163d9-and-fabio-luz).